# Unable to start postgresql service on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos, centos7, rhel

Unable to start postgresql-9.5 on CentOS 7.

I followed this page - https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation - for installing the database server on CentOS.

I tried the same after setting `setenforce 0`, and that did not help either.

I am doing all operations as `root`.

```
systemctl start postgresql-9.5.service
Job for postgresql-9.5.service failed because the control process exited with error 
code. See "systemctl status postgresql-9.5.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And here is what I get for status -

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  postgresql-9.5.service
● postgresql-9.5.service - PostgreSQL 9.5 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-9.5.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-02-18 15:20:30 EST; 2min 28s ago
  Process: 15041 ExecStartPre=/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/postgresql95-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 18 15:20:30 myserver systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL 9.5 database server...
Feb 18 15:20:30 myserver systemd[1]: postgresql-9.5.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 18 15:20:30 myserver systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL 9.5 database server.
Feb 18 15:20:30 myserver systemd[1]: Unit postgresql-9.5.service entered failed state.
Feb 18 15:20:30 myserver systemd[1]: postgresql-9.5.service failed.
```

And the contents of the different conf files are as follows -

```
[root@myserver /]# cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/postgresql-pgdg-libs.conf
/usr/pgsql-9.5/lib/

[root@myserver /]# cat /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/postgresql-9.5.conf
d /var/run/postgresql 0755 postgres postgres -

[root@myserver /]# cat /usr/pgsql-9.5/share/postgresql-9.5-libs.conf
/usr/pgsql-9.5/lib/

[root@myserver /]# cat /etc/alternatives/pgsql-ld-conf
/usr/pgsql-9.5/lib/

[root@myserver /]# cat /var/lib/alternatives/pgsql-ld-conf
auto
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/postgresql-pgdg-libs.conf

/usr/pgsql-9.5/share/postgresql-9.5-libs.conf
950
```

Googled for the error that I am seeing.
A number of folks have seen the same error, and the underlying cause is different in each case. Reading through those posts, it is not clear that I am seeing any of the already reported causes.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Make sure you have installed all packages correctly and updated yum repository sections `[base]` and `[updates]` before installation as it mentioned in the [**guide**](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation) . We have CentOS 7 with PostgreSQL 9.5 and it works perfectly fine with following steps:

```
vi /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
yum localinstall http://yum.postgresql.org/9.5/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos95-9.5-2.noarch.rpm
yum list postgres*
yum install -y postgresql95-server.x86_64 postgresql95-contrib.x86_64 postgresql95-libs.x86_64 
/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/postgresql95-setup initdb
systemctl enable postgresql-9.5.service
systemctl start postgresql-9.5.service
```

and finally, `systemctl status postgresql-9.5.service` should show you something like this:

```
postgresql-9.5.service - PostgreSQL 9.5 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-9.5.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-02-19 00:01:13 UTC; 6min ago
  Process: 10809 ExecStart=/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/pg_ctl start -D ${PGDATA} -s -w -t 300 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 10802 ExecStartPre=/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/postgresql95-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 10811 (postgres)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql-9.5.service
           ├─10811 /usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data
           ├─10812 postgres: logger process   
           ├─10814 postgres: checkpointer process   
           ├─10815 postgres: writer process   
           ├─10816 postgres: wal writer process   
           ├─10817 postgres: autovacuum launcher process   
           └─10818 postgres: stats collector process
```

Comment: The magic line was this - `# /usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/postgresql95-setup initdb`. Thanks :).

The guide mentions the above line as an alternate, if `service <name> initdb` did not work.
However, there is no guidance on what the output would look like if it did work.
In my case, I used `service <name> initdb` and it just returned me back to the command prompt. And which I  eventually found out, that it did not work.

Comment: perfect..exactly what i wanted

Comment: For me the magic lines were-[ /usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/postgresql95-setup initdb]  and [systemctl enable postgresql-9.5.service]

Comment: In my case the initdb-script was executed by a non-root user (postgresql user). The script will create a folder 'pg_log' within the $PGDATA folder before it quits without doing anything else. 

After I deleted everything from the data folder I was able to execute initdb as root and everything was working fine. (deleting from data/ will only make sense if you can restore data or if your setup is quite new ;) )

Answer (score 17):

The most common issue is that the database cluster was not initialized.  You can initialize it easily by running the postgresql-XX-setup script with the `initdb` command, e.g.

```
sudo /usr/pgsql-11/bin/postgresql-11-setup initdb
```

Then start the Postgres service, e.g.

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql-11
```

Answer (score -1):

These steps helped me on our test server.

Connect your server via SSH.

Then switch user:

```sh
sudo su - postgres
```

Check Postgres status:

```sh
pg_ctl status
```

Stop DB:

```sh
pg_ctl stop
```

Check if no server processes exist:

```sh
ps axf | grep postg
```

Start Postgres service:

```sh
sudo systemctl start postgresql.service
```

OR

```sh
sudo systemctl start postgresql
```

Then check status:

```sh
systemctl status postgresql.service ИЛИ systemctl status postgresql
```