# Unable to install PostgreSQL 9.5/PostGIS 2.3 on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos

On my CentOS 7 (x86_64) machine, I am trying to install PostgreSQL 9.5/PostGIS 2.3 via [PostgreSQL's yum repository](https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php#pg95), using [this](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/362-An-almost-idiots-guide-to-install-PostgreSQL-9.5,-PostGIS-2.2-and-pgRouting-2.1.0-with-Yum.html.) tutorial.

According to the tutorial, when I proceed to the second step.

```
sudo rpm -ivh http://yum.postgresql.org/9.5/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos95-9.5-2.noarch.rpm
```

It says:

```
Retrieving http://yum.postgresql.org/9.5/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos95-9.5-2.noarch.rpm
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
package pgdg-centos95-9.5-3.noarch (which is newer than pgdg-centos95-9.5-2.noarch) is already installed
```

Then, I try to see which packages are available in this rpm:

```
sudo yum list | grep pgdg95
```

I get,

```
libevent.x86_64               2.0.22-1.rhel7               @pgdg95
python-babel.noarch           1.3-1.rhel7                  @pgdg95
python-jinja2.noarch          2.8-7.rhel7                  @pgdg95
python-markupsafe.x86_64      0.23-11.rhel7                @pgdg95
```

Which is not according to the step number 3 in the installation tutorial. Can someone please suggest me what's wrong with the installation or are there any alternative ways to install PostgreSQL 9.5/PostGIS 2.3?

Comment: this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35492893/unable-to-start-postgresql-9-5-on-centos-7) would get it done.

Comment: @rdj7:Care to post your comment as answer? I would be happily accept it. Thanks a lot for pointing out towards the link.

Comment: ohh Sorry, I thought it would solve your issue.
Before I post any answer, I want to know what do you see when you do `yum list postgres*` and did you try first two steps in mentioned answer as it locally installs the rpm

Comment: Yes it solved the issue. Can you post your above comment as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35492893/unable-to-start-postgresql-9-5-on-centos-7/35495026#35495026).

1. Check `yum list postgres*`
   If you see desired packages it is great.
   If you still don't see desired packages then follow given steps in given answer,

`# vi /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`

`# yum localinstall http://yum.postgresql.org/9.5/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos95-9.5-2.noarch.rpm`

`# yum list postgres*`

If you check step two, we can see it does `local install` after this local installation, you should be ideally able to see desired list.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have both pgdg and EPEL repositories installed by running `sudo yum repolist`. If EPEL is not in the list, just install it `sudo yum install epel-release`.

Comment: As I can see from #sudo yum install epel-release, the EPEL repository is already installed. I have edited the question based on comments.